# Get parent directory for some files C#

Tags: c#

I'm using

```
FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath, "*",SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

filePaths are the following:

```
C:\Users\Stef\Desktop\bgdm_v2015\bgdm.dll
C:\Users\Stef\Desktop\bgdm_v2015\something.txt
C:\Users\Stef\Desktop\bgdm_v2015\folder2\file.txt
C:\Users\Stef\Desktop\bgdm_v2015\folder2\file2.txt
C:\Users\Stef\Desktop\bgdm_v2015\folder2\folder3\file.txt
```

Is there any function to get the parent directory to the files?
Like only

```
bgdm_v2015
bgdm_v2015
bgdm_v2015
folder2
folder2
folder3
```

Answer (score 5):

`Path.GetDirectoryName` returns the full path of the parent, and `Path.GetFileName` returns the last segment of the path (which can actually be a directory, not necessarily a file). So you can do this:

```
string parentDirectoryName = Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath));
```

Comment: I'm sure this is more efficient than my answer.

Comment: @itsme86, probably, because it never actually accesses the file system, it's just string manipulation.

Comment: @itsme86 whether it is or it isn't, I'd say yours is a hell of a lot more readable ;) Not that this one is bad, but...

Comment: Identical to accepted answer of duplicate question.

Comment: @hatchet right, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way to achieve your task.

**solution 1:**

```
var result = Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName("Enter Path here"));
```

**solution 2:**

```
FileInfo info = new FileInfo("Enter Path here");   
String getDirectoryName = info.Directory.Name;
```

Comment: Yes, but OP wants just the name of the parent directory, not the full path

Comment: @ThomasLevesque oh okay, i will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) to do it.

```
var fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileWithPath);
var parentName = fileInfo.Directory.Name;
```